# Detecting corrupt videos in Flutter Video Player

Tags: flutter, video

If I load a corrupt video into flutter video player using the following code the intialise future never completes nor is an error thrown... it just seems to hang.

```
videoController = VideoPlayerController.file(f)
          ..initialize().then((_) async {
            setState(() {
              
            });
          }).catchError((error){
      
            print(error);
          }).whenComplete((){
    
            print("ITS GONE IN THE whenComplete");
          });
```

I have tried using the addListener to check if it has error but this also never is true.
e.g.

```
    if (videoController.value.hasError) {
      print(videoController.value.errorDescription);
      const x = 1;
    }
```

Is there anyway to tell whether a video has failed to load without using a timeout?

---- EDIT
Also I cannot use FFmpeg to test if the video is corrupt before using it.

Comment: have you got the solution I am also looking for same?

Comment: Sorry never found one :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch the error like this

```dart
try {

  videoController = VideoPlayerController.file(f);
  await videoController.initialize();
  setState(() {});

} catch (e) {
  print(error);
}
```